# Why can't we define variables using var or let keyword in classes in typescript like this:

Tags: typescript

```
class area {    
    var length; 

    let width; 

    length:number;  // why do i need to do like this only;
    width: number;   // why do i need to do like this only;

    ...     
    ... 
}
```

Comment: why? honestly, the only answer is because that is how the language is. it's like asking why do I have to use a + symbol to add numbers.

If you question is more of a curiosity one, as to why did the language decide to do this. The answer is it's a classical way class are writing in many languages. C# and Java were likely big influences

Answer (score 1):

Typescript transpiles to Javascript. You can't do this in JS either, not in es5 nor es6.

This is what a ts class transpiles to (es5 target)

```
class Test {
  field: string = 'test';
}

// becomes:
var Test = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Test() {
        this.field = 'test';
    }
    return Test;
}());
```

Comment: got it. thanks a lot. so we just need to give the signature of the variable ie. field_name: type or field_name:type = value. Am i right ?

Comment: @PrathamPrat that's the diffrence between typescript and javascript, typescript is strongly typed you have to provide a type for every property you declare. BTW the error you mentioned is not due to the type declaration. It's because you cannot declare a property with `let or var` at class level it's not a variable it's a class property

Comment: Thanks bro for your help. I am pretty much clear now. have a good one. take care

Comment: extending Daniel's explanation, we can't do `var this.field = 'test'` in JS, thus we can't do `var field:string = 'test'` in typescript